# Alexander's horned sphere as a sub-manifold

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology

I have some questions concerning [Alexander's horned sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere). The horned sphere is an embedding (via some continuous injection $f$) of the usual 2-sphere $S^2$ into $\Bbb R^3$ in such a way that the unbounded part of $\Bbb R^3\setminus f(S^2)$ is no longer simply connected. This is usualy used to show that the Schönflies theorem does not generalize to higher dimensions.

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Is this embedding a [topological embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Topology_and_geometry) in the sense that  $S^2$ is homeomorphic to $f(S^2)\subset\Bbb R^3$ given the subspace topology?
> 2. If yes, does this means that $f(S^2)$ as a submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$? I ask this because I am not really sure whether a submanifold is necessarily endowed with the subspace topology w.r.t. the ambient space.

Maybe I can phrase this as a more general question.

> **Question:** Given an $n$-dimensional (topological) manifold $M$ and an embedding $f:M\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^m$. Do we always have that $M$ is homeomorphic to $f(M)\subset \Bbb R^m$ with the subspace topology?

Comment: In fact, that's what an embedding means: the map is a homeomorphism onto its image wit the subspace topology.

Comment: @MikeMiller As far as I know, an embedding is injective and continuous, which does not mean that it maps homeomorphic onto its image. For example, I can embedd $[0,1)$ into $\Bbb R^2$ with $f([0,1)]=S^1$ but obviously $[0,1)\not\cong S^1$. This is where my uncertainty arises. Something like this example is also called an *embedding* but is certainly not what I am looking for. Of course $[0,1)$ is no manifold. So *it could be* that an embedding for manifolds still means being homeomorphic to the image. But then, this is the answer I am looking for. Is this some result that I can see easily?

Comment: That is not what should be called an embedding. It's an injective map, no more. You need the definition of embedding to be what I said above (or you need to demand your domain is compact, which you have here).

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you. It seems my definition of *embedding* is the problem then. Is this the general rule? An embedding of $A$ into $B$ is a structure preserving injection $f:A\to B$ that is an isomorphism between $A$ and $f(A)$?

Comment: @MikeMiller: Actually, there is a disagreement concerning the definition of an embedding. Compare http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Embedding. With that definition the horned sphere does not define a topological embedding in the category of manifolds. My take on this is that "homeomorphism onto its image" is a definition of  an embedding in the sense of general topology but not in the sense of manifold topology.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Sure, but I am not sure if this subtlety is helpful for OP.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I think I understand this other definition from you link, but I cannot see how it is different from the other one given above, at least in the case of topological manifolds.

Comment: @M.Winter: With the other definition, the horned sphere is not an embedded sphere (is not a submanifold either).